# I have a list in values of a dictionary and I want the first index of the list. How to iterate through it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My dict looks like this.

```
{'a':0,'is_target':False,'properties':[{'id':19,'title':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':2}},{'id':20,'title':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':2}}]}
```

I want to group all the id's.

So Far I have tried using maps,also tried creating a new dict from the items and iterating over it. but I couldn't group.

Comment: I'm curious to see how did you use `map`!

Comment: Could you please tell in which way you want to group it?

Comment: I want the list of all id's together.

Comment: is properties is a list of  dictionaries of such structure {'id':'19,'title':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':2}} could be please confirm on the closing of first flower bracket as i did but not visible in code you pasted?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to find all the 'id's from this dict. You could do -

```
final_list = []
for i in d['properties']:
    final_list.append(i['id'])
```

`final_list` has all the 'id's.

Comment: perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Accepting the answer would put a green tick below the vote counter, kindly do if you feel this answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`parthagar` answer equal to:

```
d = {'a':0,
'is_target':False,
 'properties':[{'id':19,'title':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':2}},
             {'id':20,'title':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':2}}]}

final_list = [i["id"]  for i in d['properties']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to these via *list comprehension*

```
ids = [i['id'] for i in d['properties']]
```

> ```
> [19, 20]
> ```